# How to convert java Map to delimited format

Tags: java, dictionary

For example:

```
key1: 1,2,3,4
key2: 5,6
```

will convert to

```
key1|key2
1|5
2|6
3
4
```

And I know if we do this iteratively, there a lot of ways which are not efficient. I am wondering if there is any built-in methods or anything which can transform them directly.

```
HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<String, String>;
h1.put("key1", "1,2,3,4"); 
h1.put("key2", "5,6");
```

need to print out as pipe delimited format:

```
key1|key2
1|5
2|6
3
4
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - please clarify what the input is. (Your title says a map, but `key1: 1,2,3,4 key2: 5,6` does not look like one).

Comment: Are you having just `two` keys?

Comment: Could this be a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`?

Comment: Don't confuse efficiency with conciceness. Hand-coded iteration **is very efficient**, in many cases better than using a library method if it would require any kind of conversion.

Comment: what happens when you introduce `key3: 7,8,9,10`?  Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik For values, I concatenated strings with comma.

Comment: @Wug Yes, I assumed this is infinite expandable, in other words, it should contain infinite many keys with infinite many of their children.

Comment: @Wug Our legacy system can only read pipe delimited spreadsheet. However the new program someone else wrote only takes dictionary, so we need an adaptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class like this one:

```
import java.util.*;

class LegacyGlueifier
{
    private LegacyGlueifier()
    {
    }

    public static String generateLegacyDataset(Map<String, String> data)
    {
        final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        final int width = data.size();

        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet())
        {
            String[] values = entry.getValue().split(",");
            changeDims(lists, width, values.length + 1);

            for (int j = 0; j < values.length; ++j) setValue(lists, j + 1, i, values[j]);
            setValue(lists, 0, i, entry.getKey());
            ++i;
        }

        return stringify(lists);
    }

    private static void changeDims(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists, int width, int newHeight)
    {
        while (lists.size() < newHeight) lists.add(arrayListOfSize(width));
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> arrayListOfSize(int w)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(w);
        while (list.size() < w) list.add(null);
        return list;
    }

    private static void setValue(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists, int row, int col, String val)
    {
        ArrayList<String> temp = lists.get(row);
        temp.set(col, val);
        // System.out.println("SET: " + row + " " + col + ": " + val);
    }

    private static String swapNullWithEmpty(String s)
    {
        if (s == null) return "";
        return s;
    }

    private static String stringify(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (ArrayList<String> sublist : lists)
        {
            if (sublist.size() != 0) sb.append(swapNullWithEmpty(sublist.get(0)));
            for (int i = 1; i < sublist.size(); ++i)
                sb.append("|").append(swapNullWithEmpty(sublist.get(i)));
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Invocation is `String dataset = LegacyGlueifier.generateLegacyDataset(myMap)`

[I ran it through a basic test case to see if it worked](http://ideone.com/rQVAVE) but I'd still test it more thoroughly since you're going to be using it.

Its time complexity is somewhere between linear to the total number of comma delimited fields in the original dataset and linear to the total number of fields in the output dataset (including blank ones).

Answer (score 0):

This will do the transformation. The code looks long an complex but the overall complexity is still O(n): every key and value is touched a constant number of times, regardless of the size of the map.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = getMap();
    Map<String, String[]> map2 = new TreeMap<>();

    // (1) Read the map into an intermediate map and
    // get the number of rows needed
    int maxSize = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String[] array = entry.getValue().split(",");
        maxSize = array.length > maxSize ? array.length : maxSize;
        map2.put(entry.getKey(), array);
    }

    // (2) prepare the table structure
    List<List<String>> table = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (maxSize + 1); i++) {
        table.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    // (3) read the values into the table structure
    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        table.get(0).add(entry.getKey());
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
            if (i < entry.getValue().length) {
                table.get(i + 1).add(entry.getValue()[i]);
            } else {
                table.get(i + 1).add("");
            }
        }
    }

    // (4) dump the table
    for (List<String> row : table) {
        StringBuilder rowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isFirst = true;
        for (String value : row) {
            if (isFirst) {
                isFirst = false;
            } else {
                rowBuilder.append('|');
            }
            rowBuilder.append(value);
        }
        System.out.println(rowBuilder.toString());
    }

}

private static Map<String, String> getMap() {
    Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "1,2,3,4");
    map.put("key2", "5,6");
    map.put("key3", "7,8,9");
    return map;
}
```

The result for this sample is:

```
key1|key2|key3
1|5|7
2|6|8
3||9
4||
```

---

(first answer, based on a wrong guess)

Assuming, 5 and 6 are *values* for *keys* 1 and 2, then this is a good solution:

```
public static void dumpMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry:map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("%s|%s%n", entry.getKey(), nullSafe(entry.getValue()));
    }
}

private static String nullSafe(String value) {
    return value == null ? "" : value;
}
```

It is O(n) and we can't do it more efficient, because we have to access every key/value pair once to print it.

(unless we can use parallel computing ;))

Comment: No, the map goes like `{"key1":"1,2,3,4", "key2":"5,6"}`. It's not this trivial, you must iterate over all values (after parsing) in parallel and create a printf template according to the number of map entries.

Comment: Marko, I created the answer before Victor showed us how the map really looks like

Comment: I commented before seeing that, too :) I base it on just the spreadsheet-style display that was originally there.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, actually yes, the output should be in column format